# Read process output line by line

Tags: comint, subprocess, compilation-mode

If there a way to read the output of a subprocess line by line, or at least to get it in small batches?

I have a subprocess doing work in the background, and printing a line every time it completes a task. There are many such small tasks, so I would like to show a progress indicator; unfortunately, my filter function receives output in batches of 10 to 20 lines, which makes the progress display much more jittery than it really is.

When I run that same process as a `compile` process, the output is displayed smoothly; I can't figure the trick that `compilation-mode` uses to achieve this.

Comment: Is your filter doing anything special to restrict the flow -- have you tried just printing messages for every "string" that goes through the filter to see what the `string`s look like?  E.g., `(defun my-process-filter (proc string) (message "%s\n" string))`  I added a new-line so the `string`s are clearly separated.

Comment: Nope, nothing special; I'm essentially just printing the messages.

Comment: This, most likely, is a property of the spawned process. It needs to flush its output more often. Compilers typically emit error messages on lstderr, which is line based.

Comment: @Lindydancer: I wrote the tool that gets spawned, and it already flushes after each line.

Comment: Maybe try using `compilation-start` and remove code until you see the jittery effect? BTW, I don't think anyone will be help you with this question unless you post enough code to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I know of for this is setting `process-adaptive-read-buffering` to `nil` before starting the process.  I don't know whether this will help with your situation or not.

Comment: Ah, yes, I tried that; no luck though. The surprising part is that calling the process through compilation-mode seems to work much better; I wonder what happens there.